# SDL_GAMECONTROLLERCONFIG vs. SDL_GameControllerAddMappingsFromFile

Tags: c++, sdl-2, gamepad

I am using SDL_GameControllerAddMappingsFromFile in my game and I have added a new game controller to the gamecontrollerdb.txt file. I used SDL2 Gamepad Tool to create the mapping and added it to the gamecontrollerdb.txt file. If I set the environment variable SDL_GAMECONTROLLERCONFIG to point to the mapping then everything works. However the mapping does not work when I remove the environment variable even though the same mapping is added to the file.

I have used the appropriate tool check.py as specified here: https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB

The tools says that the file looks good. I am using the latest officiell release of SDL2 (2.0.9) and running under Windows 10. My code is cross platform and I have tested it under Raspian with the same discouraging result.

Windows recognize the Bluetooth controller with the correct name and I get no error message when loading the file (it seems to me as there is no error checking at all when the file is read).

I have tested the code with several other game controllers and they work as expected on Windows / OSX and Linux.

```
if (SDL_GameControllerAddMappingsFromFile("gamecontrollerdb.txt") == -1) {
    std::cout << "Warning: Failed to load game controller mappings: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

The code that actually uses the controller are found here:
https://github.com/drpatrik/combatris/blob/develop/combatris/src/combatris.cpp

I would expect the controller to be recognized since the mapping obviously works and is added to the file.

Answer (score 3):

I found out what the problem was. Some gamepads are treated as Joystick which means that you need to turn on both gamepad and joystick events and also listen to the attach events from both:

```
SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
SDL_GameControllerEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
```

as well as:

```
...
case SDL_JOYDEVICEADDED:
case SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED:
```